# Función AJAX no envía datos por POST a un archivo PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

Tengo una función ajax que envía datos por post a un archivo PHP llamado "doc", pero no envía los datos.

La funcion:

```html
$('.doc').click(function(){
    let url = "doc/doc.php";   
    
    fila = $(this);
    id = parseInt($(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text());   
    
    $.ajax({                        
       type: "POST",                 
       url: url,    
       dataType:"json",                
       data: {id:id}
    })
})
```

El código que recibe los datos:

```html
$id = (isset($_POST['id'])) ? $_POST['id'] : ''; 


echo $id;
```

Mi problema está en que en mi archivo  **doc.php**  no recibo los datos que le estoy mandando por medio de ajax.

La direccion de mi archivo php es la correcta.

Comment: El código debe ir como texto y no como imagen. Por favor haz clic en [edit] y cambia lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: Hola, debes agregar el código para facilitar la comprensión de tu problema, las imágenes solo deben ser ilustrativas o como ejemplos, edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que creas necesario, evita subir imágenes o cerraran tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que esto funcione correctamente debes tener un elemento con la `clase de css` en el `HTML` de la siguiente manera:

```html
<input type="submit" value="boton para enviar ajax" class="doc" />
```

Ahora en la funcion con  Jquery. Recuerda incluir la `CDN de jQuery`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<script>

$('.doc').click(function(){
    let url = "doc/doc.php";   
    let fila = $(this); // no la usas deberias borrarla
    let id = parseInt($(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text());   
    
    
    $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: url',
            data: JSON.stringify({id:id}),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                // aqui pocesa tu respuesta
                console.log(data)
            }
     });
    
})


</script>
```

Ahora en el archivo de destino:

1. Recuerda que estas enviando datos en formato `json` por lo tanto, no puedes acceder a los valores mediante la variable `$_POST`
2. Debes convertir el `json` en `array` u `Object`

Este seria tu documento `doc/doc.php`

```html
<?php
$postBody = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

//asi accedes a los valores
var_dump($postBody->id );
?>
```